# инкрементация для бд

Tags: php, mysql

есть рабочий запрос в бд для записи адреса, возникла необходимость присваивать каждому адресу свой номер.Пробовал задавать `$count=1` а после запроса в бд увеличивать значение `$count++` , пробовал в самом запросе `+1` делать, и в общем без результатов. На всякий случай запрос

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `".PREFIX_USR."delivery_address`
                            (`id_personl_data`,`country`,`province`,`city`,`street`,`house`,`apartment`,`number`)
                        VALUES ( '$personal_id','".$row[$j][0]."','".$row[$j][1]."','".$row[$j][2]."',
                                '".$row[$j][3]."','".$row[$j][4]."','".$row[$j][5]."','".$count."') ");
```

Comment: вообще count++ должен дать результат если вы этот запрос выполняете в цикле. А вот тот ли результат вам нужен, и действительно ли ваш цикл отрабатывает более одного раза - это другой вопрос. Если вам нужна сквозная нумерация всех записей в таблице - то лучше сделать колонку auto_increment

Comment: Вставка значения из подзапроса с `COUNT (*)` выглядит интересной идеей в этом случае.

Comment: непонятно какой вам number нужен? автоинкремент 1.2.3.4.5.6.7 и т.д. или же 101,102, 103 и т.д. какой в общем номер нужно?

Answer (score 1):

Полю `number` в базе поставь атрибут `AUTO_INCREMENT`, а после в запросе просто опускай это поле или передавай `NULL`.

Comment: для 1 пользователя прокатит, но для нескольких ( будет у `n`го юзера адреса начинаться с 100 200 и тд)

Comment: Тут тогда посылать перед этим другой запрос и узнавать последний "number"

Answer (score 0):

Создайте для этого триггер и ваша проблема решиться.